# Changing from MSQL to MYSQLI real_escape_string $link

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Currently I am using `mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['new_name']));` and it is working fine however when I change it to `mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['new_name']));` I am getting `Message: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`

I am using codeigniter so my DB connection would be in the form of `$this->db`.

Comment: You didn't do the slightest research. If you had visited the php documentation and saw the mysqli_real_escape_string page you would know that it needs 2 parameters. what you want to escape and the link to the connection

Comment: @AliTrixx Yes I did but because I am using CI I got confused as to what the `$link` var should be

Comment: By upvoting a bad question you aren't doing any good for the poster, nor for the site. Explain their fault in the comments instead of a 'comforting upvote'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of escaping, use Codeigniters query binding. Also use `$this->input->post()` as opposed to directly accessing `$_POST`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?";
$this->db->query($query, array($this->input->post('new_name'));
```

If you must use escaping (the wrong way), then use:

```
$new_name = $this->db->escape_str($this->input->post('new_name'));
```